# Angular 2 support in Visual studio 2013

Tags: .net, angular, visual-studio-2013

I will be developing a web application in angular 2 , may i know the technical feasibility or challenges in visual studio 2013.
Will that be possible to work on angular 2 in Visual studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

You can work with your notepad in Angular 2 if you want.

Let me explain it to you : when you code in, let's say C#, you need to compile your code. Visual Studio does that for you, because it is its purpose.

When you create an Agular project, you also need to compile your code (from Typescript to Javascript). This is done with the tool provided by the Angular team, which the Angular CLI (there are several tools out there, but let's say that you start in Angular and you follow their tutorial).

This CLI is used through a command line : this means that if you have a command line in your IDE, you will be able to work with.

And I'm volountarily not talking about IDe features, because I don't think that it is what you asked.

Comment: Is it possible to code, compile and perform all other operation in VS2013 for angular 2. Does VS2013 support all the feature of angular 2. if not which version of VS should i use?

Comment: I thought my answer was clear ... The CLI will handle all of that for you. Every feature of Angular is contained into the CLI. If you want to write code, you can use anything, even your notepad or vim.

Comment: Is all the version of Typescript supported in Visual studio 2013?

Comment: ... For the last time **the compiler for Typescript is included in Angular CLI. You don't need anything but the CLI to create an Angular project**.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. any links related to creation of CLI in angular and its basics

Comment: Finally :D **[Here is the documentation for a quick start](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart)**